# ¿Por qué no puedo iniciar sesión, con Google o con Facebook desde el móvil?

Tags: bug, web-móvil, login

Cuando intento iniciar sesión desde el móvil, teniendo activa mi cuanta de Google, solo me sale un mensaje con el texto:

> Pedido falto de condición, puede ser falsificado

Lo mismo me sucede si intento iniciar sesión usando mi cuenta de Facebook.

He intentado crear un nuevo inicio de sesión, desde mi conexión por la PC, cuando recibo el mensaje de confirmación, por el email y presiono el link, me remite a una página con el siguiente error.

> [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta situación no me ha permitido iniciar sesión desde mi móvil.

Comment: Cuando te refieres a _desde el móvil_, ¿puedes indicar a qué tipo de web accedes? ¿A la versión móvil o la adaptada? Puedes ver cuál es en la parte inferior de la página

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Bueno parece que el problema está por ahí, cuando trato de acceder a la _Versión para móvil_ así dice en la parte inferior de la página, da ese error, pero cuando accedo a la versión adaptada funciona sin problemas. Claro, de eso me dí cuenta después de formular la pregunta, de todas maneras me gustaría acceder a la _Versión para móvil_ es más elegante y similar a la que abro por la PC, que ahora me doy cuenta que también es la _Versión para móvil_

Comment: siento comentarte que las versiones para moviles estan muy atras en las consideraciones del equipo de desarrollo... o sea, no le dan mucha pelota y la app por ejemplo ya no tiene soporte....

Comment: @gbianchi Si, entiendo que el sitio no está enfocado al acceso de la red móvil, por razones obvias; me es suficiente poder acceder y revisar la bandeja de entrada y tal ves visualizar alguna pregunta o respuesta. Intentar responder desde el móvil, seria muy incomodo, con el diseño de la versión para móvil es suficiente.

Comment: tal y como comenta @gbianchi, la versión móvil está bastante desfasada y la versión completa es cada vez mejor desde el móvil. Por ello, yo recomiendo usar esta última. Créeme, se ve bastante bien